# Application won't run correctly from %localappdata%

Tags: c#, .net, windows, deployment, clickonce

My application run from "...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\some guid", but it won't fully work (some third-party reg free COM DLL files don't work.. There is no exception, but nothing happens), but if I copy the whole folder to, for example, C:\, all works.

How can I fix this problem?

Update: I tried to copy the application folder to the same location (from "...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\some guid\folder" to "...\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\some guid\copy of folder" ) and then all works, but still not in the installed folder.

Comment: Do you use registry entries?

Comment: No, however I do have reg free com objects..

Comment: If it's only up to your 3rd party dlls maybe they have the wrong working directory

Comment: but why would it work if I copy the application directory to (any!) other place?

Comment: Notable for the missing info: what did the debugger tell you?

Comment: @HansPassant The debugger is just moving over the call to the method of the external dll (just as if it would work, but the method itself doesn's seem to execute - nothing really happens)

Answer (score 0):

Does that path have spaces inside? For example, `c:\users\my computer\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\` (notice the space between `my` and `computer`). Does your code use that path somehow? If yes, try to enclose the path with double quotes.

Comment: I think the path is correct, the application start okay, but when I (in the running application) attempt to use the 3rd party dlls nothing happens. I also tried making a copy of the folder in the same location, and then it works.. just not in the installed folder.